# Get items before and after an item - SQL Query

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL, so I need your help on a query.  Basically I have a Database of ZipCodes and I want to get 3 items before the selected ZipCode and 3 items after.  The Query that I came up with is pretty bad...

```
WITH numberedlogtable AS
(
SELECT *
 FROM dbo.US
)

SELECT *
FROM numberedlogtable
WHERE ZipCode IN (SELECT ZipCode+i
             FROM numberedlogtable
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT -1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) n
             WHERE ZipCode='91803')
```

I picked up a sample Query from somewhere and successfully converted it for my use.  The only problem is that this Query returns current item and the next item.  Instead, it should returns previous 3 items, current item, and next three items.

Comment: I think it should be noted that unless zip code is guaranteed to be unique all answers below fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a common table expression (the `WITH` part) producing a numbered sequence:

```
WITH NumberedZipCodes AS
(SELECT SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ZipCode) AS RowNumber, *
FROM ZipCodes)

SELECT * From NumberedZipCodes
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN
(SELECT RowNumber FROM NumberedZipCodes WHERE ZipCode=91803) - 3
AND (SELECT RowNumber FROM NumberedPerson WHERE ZipCode=91803) + 3
```

Normally in SQL there is no such concept as the previous or next items in a match. Actually, unless an order by clause is specified the rows are returned in any order that the sql engine find suitable. To make a query like this, an order has to be applied and index numbers generated. That's done in NumberedZipCodes. The second part is just a query to get the data out of it.

To have the query run efficiently, make sure that there is an index on the `ZipCode` column.

Answer (score 4):

"Before" and "after" only have meaning in the context of ordering. Assuming you wish to order by ZIP code, selecting the desired ZIP code and 2 rows after it could be done like this:

```
SELECT TOP(3) *
FROM numberedlogtable
WHERE ZipCode >= '91803'
ORDER BY ZipCode
```

Selecting 3 rows before:

```
SELECT TOP(3) *
FROM numberedlogtable
WHERE ZipCode < '91803'
ORDER BY ZipCode DESC
```

Put UNION ALL between these two queries to make it one, if that's what you wish.

You can play with it in the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8923b/3).

Answer (score 0):

> 3 items before the selected ZipCode and 3 items afte

SQL is set based, it has no defined order UNLESS YOU DEFINE ONE (with order by).

Now, lets not get into the more complex stuff - FURST you have to create an order asking for the central item, then in a second query you can ask for the other 6. Sorry, no other way. x+3 would be doable with a Top 4 statement and a filter etc. - but the 3 before will definitely require a second query.

All assume you creata query / view that has
* THe zipCodes in a defined order
* a row number once you filter it, used to define (a) the "current line" as well as filter for all with smaller lines.

But you need an order manually first.